# Is there a way to access google services with pre-built Chromium ASan binaries?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, address-sanitizer

I am trying to investigate a UAF in Chromium. The UAF steps require accessing google services (sync, password sync, etc..). Anyway to enable google services for pre-built asan chromium binaries?

e.g. https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/chromium-browser-asan/o/win32-release_x64%2Fasan-win32-release_x64-1021933.zip?generation=1657241429295082&alt=media

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After March 15th 2022, Google limited access to Google services on Chromium. Solution to enabling sync was found here: stackoverflow.com/a/67459416/19243542. I launch Chromium with the command line switches and was able to log into Goolge sync, etc... solved.